# MVC Partial View not hitting HTTP Post on controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view that should run a HttpPost on a controller, but its not. On my main page I have the following partial view

```
 <div class="box">
     @Html.Action("AddNote", "Member", new { MemberId = Model.Id })
 </div>
```

The partial view is as follows -

```
@model GMS.Core.Models.AddMemberNoteModel

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNote", "Member", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MemberId)

    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Note, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Type note ..." })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note)

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" value="Save" />
    </span>
    </div>
}
```

The trouble is when the submit button is pressed, the HttpPost method is not hit. When the page loads, the first actionresult is hit.

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult AddNote(string memberId)
    {
        AddMemberNoteModel model = new AddMemberNoteModel();

        model.MemberId = Convert.ToInt32(memberId);

        return PartialView("AddNote", model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddNote(AddMemberNoteModel model)
    {
        model.DateCreated = DateTime.Now;
        model.CreatedBy = ((CustomPrincipal)HttpContext.User).Id;

        model.LastUpdated = DateTime.Now;
        model.LastUpdateBy = ((CustomPrincipal)HttpContext.User).Id;

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            _memberService.AddNote(model);

            this.TempData["Notification"] = "A note has been added.";

            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Member", new { id = model.MemberId });
        }
        else
        {
            return PartialView(model);
        }
    }
```

**Rendered HTML**

```
 <form action="/Member/AddNote/7537" method="post"><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field MemberId must be a number." data-val-required="The MemberId field is required." id="MemberId" name="MemberId" type="hidden" value="7537" /><div class="input-group">
<input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-required="The Note field is required." id="Note" name="Note" type="text" value="" />
    <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="Note" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" value="Save" />
        </span>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Is a POST actually happening? What does your browser dev tools tell you?

Comment: @mxmissile no post happens. No errors in browser tools either.

Comment: Post your rendered html. If no post is happening then the culprit has to be there.

Comment: I have updated the post with the rendered HTML.

Comment: perhaps decorate this with the post attribute same as the other one
`[Authorize]
    public ActionResult AddNote(string memberId)`

Comment: Something is missing, you dont see a POST in your browser tools network tab?

Comment: Nope, no POST from what I can see. The page simply refreshes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was I had the Add Note form embedded inside another form.

```
@(Html.BeginForm())
{
..........
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddNote", "Member", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.MemberId)

    <div class="input-group">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Note, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "Type note ..." })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Note)

    <span class="input-group-btn">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat" value="Save" />
    </span>
    </div>
}
}
```